# Is there an open Chemical database that includes GHS/CLP classifications?

Tags: reference-request, databases

I'm looking for a Chemical database that

- is up to date (via a firm, experts or crowdsourcing)
- is open and free to use (best via an API)
- contains the CLP/GHS classifications for chemicals

I have not found any database that has these three points (e.g. ChemSpider is actually not really open and does not contain CLP/GHS classifications)

I was really hoping any of you might know of one?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're a Dutch neighbour, the [European Chemicals Agency](http://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals) might be an option.

Comment: That one looks excellent. Do you know if there's any API to access the chemical proprties + classification?

Comment: @WillemMulder I'm afraid I don't know that. [IUCLID](http://iuclid.eu/) might be another place to look at.

Comment: Hi, any updates with this question? Do you guys know of an API that can provide me with GHS info for a given substance / CAS#?