# API to get GHS info given substance / CAS #

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, databases

Is there an API that can provide the GHS info for a given substance / CAS #?

If not, which website is the most extensive to get GHS info for a given substance / CAS # in human-readable format?

Comment: It looks like you already found this prior question, but just to point out this related post to future readers: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/16583/41556