# Open MSDS (GHS/CLP) database API by CAS#

Tags: software, cheminformatics

I am looking for an open API to a database that provides GHS/CLP classifications.
I am aware this is a [duplicate](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16583/is-there-an-open-chemical-database-that-includes-ghs-clp-classifications), however the post in question never provided an answer since, as far as I can tell IUCLID 6 does not have a publically accessible API or I never found it (despite it being called a public API ? Im a bit confused on this but chances are I simply missed the API)

Comment: https://github.com/TomLent1/GHScrunch Could be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Khoi Van wrote [find_sds](https://github.com/khoivan88/find_sds), a Python-based implementation to collect SDS based on the CAS registry number submitted to the command line.  The lookup then considers ChemBlink, VWR, Fisher Scientific, TCI Chemicals, ChemicalSafety, and Fluorochem as sources for the pdf.  It is a project with a permissive GPL3 license.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to download PDFs directly which is not what im looking for right now since I would love to avoid parsing PDFs but if all fails this might be a nice alternative, thank you!

Comment: @Julien "as sources for the pdf", yeah.  I see the author offers an [management/inventory program](https://github.com/khoivan88/open_enventory-modified_for_US); following the [documentation](https://open-enventory.gitbook.io/user-guides/), there is a cross-link for the demo of the [inventory](http://enventory.chemie.uni-kl.de/inventar/index.php?db_name=storage&user=demo&password=demo&desired_action=login&user_lang=en&loginTarget=inventory). Search (left magnifying glass), then addition of a new sample (`+` next to erlenmeyer) opens a pan, entering `109-99-9` and `read from suppliers` fetches

Comment: the strings of GHS codes and hazard statements and symbols.  With code analysis / contact with the authors, one possibly could extract the algorithm used to provide a "standalone" version (enter the CAS, report the codes back to the CLI). The example with CAS 109-99-9 is about tetrahydrofurane.